# How to make child looks like relative in sanity.io?

Tags: content-management-system, sanity, headless-cms

I have a formed structure of documents:

```
{
  name: 'item',
  title: 'item',
  type: 'document',
    fields: [
    {
      name: 'category',
      type: 'reference',
      title: 'category',
      to: { type: 'settingCategory' },
      validation: Rule => Rule.required(),
    },
  ],
}
```

I don't want to change a structure in the desk. But I need to show `category` in the studio user interface like a 'relative folder'. Is it possible?

--UPD

In the `@sanity/desk-tool/structure-builder` now I have this structure:

```js
export default () =>
  SB.list()
    .id('root')
    .title('root')
    .items([
      SB.documentTypeListItem('item'), //all items are here, and they have a category by field in the each other
      ...
          ])
          ...
        ),
        ...
    ])
```

But I need to show category like a parent. And I need to bind somehow my value of category inside with `SB.list()`. Category, is an independent document with a fields, I've already have it.

--UPD2

I mean, I now have one relative `.documentTypeListItem(name:item)`, and it has items with field `tags`. Every tag field has one value. Now I have a problem, i need to separate this `item`s according this tag field value into `documentTypeListItem(name:tagOne)`, `documentTypeListItem(name:tagTwo)` etc in the my dashboard.

--UPD3

If relocation is impossible. Alternatively it will be ok to show an icon for the item according the selected category. Something like this, but it doesn't work:

```js
name: 'item',
  title: 'item',
  type: 'document',
  fields: [
    {
      name: 'categoryCheck',
      type: 'string',
      title: 'category',
      options:  {
        list:[
          {
            name: 'one',
            title: 'One',
            type: 'string',
            icon: 'FaIconOne',
          },
          {
            name: 'two',
            title: 'two',
            type: 'string',
            icon: 'FaIconTwo',
          },
        ],
        layout: 'select'
      },
    },
    ],
  preview: {
    select: {
      title: 'title.name',
      media: 'categoryCheck.icon'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to understand the question better - do you want to be able to add new `settingCategory`-entries while editing an `item` without leaving the page?

Comment: @bjoerge any your clue can help

Comment: @kizoso I feel confident we can figure out a way to solve this, but I need a better grip on exactly what you're trying to achieve. It might be easier to move the conversation to https://slack.sanity.io and then come back here and update the question + answer once we've figured it out? Would that be feasible for you?

Comment: @thomax thanks for the invite! It will be very helpfull! I will definitely write there in the coming days.